# How would I create a form/application to overlay my DirectX Full Screen Games? - Visual Basic

Tags: directx, overlay, fullscreen

I was wondering if anyone out there knew how to create a form overlay for a FULLSCREEN directX game such as World of Warcraft, using visual basic? I have created an useful application I wanted to use ontop of the fullscreen game. I've searched for hours, only to find that it is possible, but I couldn't find any code for this to be possible. I've found that it uses DirectX to achieve this. It's important not to be confused with windowed mode, my application works on top of that, but not on top of a fullscreen mode.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you would be best using a solution like this; http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c/62019-c-non-hooked-external-directx-overlay.html

The problem with hooking into games to draw overlays is they quite often detect it as a cheat and ban you. Make sure you do not interact with the game's own process and implement the overlay using this method and you should be fine.